# How to add images to DB Browser for sqlite that are stored in drawable folder?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room, db-browser-sqlite

I am trying to pre-populate a room database with some data using DB Browser for sqlite.

I have a table defined with (name: String, score:Int, image:Int). That image field stores an image from drawable folder so the example for an insert would be :

```
INSERT INTO player (name,score,image) VALUES ("Mike", 31, R.drawable.mike)
```

Since the table field is Int, DB Browser wont let me store R.drawable.mike which is the image location in android studio as it expects a number. Error :

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such column: R.drawable.mike
At line 1:
INSERT INTO player (name,score,image) VALUES ("Mike", 31, R.drawable.mike)
```

I have tried using a BLOB type for image but it returns the same error as above.

Any ideas on how I can do this ? If I define image to be a string how can I make android studio read "R.drawable.mike" as id location later in the code?

Or how can I prepopulate a room database with such data in some other way ?

Comment: I am considering using a string anyway and then converting it later like this (but in kotlin) :


String name = "your_drawable";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);

Comment: Clearly this piece of data is a string: `R.drawable.mike`. I'm not familiar with android studio etc. Does it at some point map to an int? That must occur in your application code somewhere.

Comment: I believe that at runtime it maps to the location of the image in the resources folder. Android studio considers that to be an int as it points to a location in the phone's memory. But the DB browser does not have such structure/system.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the bit of code that is meant to utilise this piece of data.